# Reg ex to match numbers after letter

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to come up with a Reg Ex that finds the numbers after a particular prefix. In this example I use the letters 'JOB'. So if I type 'JOB2324 new order received' I need to return 2324. The number of numbers after JOB can vary. E.g 'some info about JOB9883789' should return 9883789.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `preg_match_all('#JOB(\d+)#',$yourtypein,$match);` then `print_r($match[1])` you would get what you wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("@JOB([0-9]+)@", $string, $matches)
```

Should do it.

Of course if you have an 'isolated' text like JOB1234, then

```
$number = substr($string,3);
```

is much faster. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Thanks this worked, providing I used $matches[1] to get the number out. The substr one won't work in this case as the string is an email subject line that can vary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Reg Ex` you could use `substr` function

`<?php
echo substr('JOB9883789', 3);`

Since  keyword `JOB` does not change in your case.